# Missing Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll in runtime

Tags: google-drive-api, nuget, uwp

I just updated Google.Apis.Drive.v2 to version 1.16.0.609 and right after that started getting runtime exception "missing Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll". I put all the logic in regards to the google drive access into a separate assembly. I have an application referencing that assembly. Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll is really missing from that assembly and from the application.

I managed to fix it adding nuget Microsoft.Bcl.Async to the application but all that looks way too strange. First of all the application is UWP application and technically Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll shouldn't be necessary to it at all. Another thing is even if it is necessary for some reasons why it is not picked up as Google.Apis.Drive.v2 nuget dependency?

Comment: According to the solution in the [reported issue in github](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/353), try to verify if your ".NET framework is patched. Microsoft released patches to .NET to allow Portable Class Libraries to properly find the appropriate runtime 
(KB2468871). If you are seeing the above exception (or something like it), it means you're missing the latest .NET framework patches." Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you tell me how to check it? However it is unlikely that I don't have it. I see this KB2468871 was published on 6/8/2011. I have Windows 10 1607 with all most recent updates and VS 2015 Update 3 with all most recent updates.

Comment: I am seeing this as well with the Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 v1.16.0.586.  It was working fine with Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 v 1.14.1.574.